# Linear-gradient Complex Figure

Tags: html, css, background-image, gradient, background-color

I want to create a complex linear-gradient figure.

First, the gradient tilted 110deg with multi-position color stops.
These adjacent colors having the same color stop value create a striped effect.

background: linear-gradient(110deg, #4587B3 10% 12%, #DCDCDC 12% 55%, white 55%);

However, after 55% last 2 colors should be ordinary horizontal linear-gradient(green, red). Just the gradual color transition, without the striped effect.

So, it should combine first tilted (110deg, striped), then horizontal (gradient).

I mean like background: linear-gradient(110deg, #4587B3 10% 12%, #DCDCDC 12% 55%, white 55%, green, red);

I inserted them as 2 separate code snippets.
Please advise how to combine them in 1.

```css
#vlikar{
  background: linear-gradient(110deg, #4587B3 10% 12%, #DCDCDC 12% 55%, white 55%);
  height: 170px; 
  width: 1349px; 
}
#vlikar2{
  background: linear-gradient(green, red);
  height: 80px; 
  width: 1429px; 
}
```

```html
<section id="vlikar">
 </section> 
 
 <section id="vlikar2">
 </section>
```

Comment: Please add an image of the desired result.

Comment: Can you explain a bit the purpose of the -90px margin? Is this element to sit at the very top of the viewport (ie the top 90px never to be seen?).

Comment: @Kosh @A Haworth I replied with snippet in the new answer. 
I think it will be more understandable in such a way.

Comment: You say the negative margin isn’t important, but it makes a difference. Please change your question to remove it as it was the difficult part to answer!

Comment: @AHaworth Thanks, changed.

Answer (score 1):

background-image can have several actual images (including gradient images).

This snippet replaces the white in your first linear-gradient with transparent. As it is the first in the list it will overlay any subsequent images.

The second linear gradient is green, red but it accounts for the 90px negative margin by making the first 90px solid green, it then begins to merge with the red at the point that the element is in view.

```css
#vlikar {
  background: linear-gradient(110deg, #4587B3 10% 12%, #DCDCDC 12% 55%, transparent 55%), linear-gradient(green 0 90px, red);
  height: 170px;
  margin: -90px 0px 0px 0px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #696969;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 1349px;
}

#vlikar2 {
  margin: 90px -80px;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(green, red);
  height: 80px;
  width: 1429px;
}
```

```html
<section id="vlikar">
</section>

<section id="vlikar2">
</section>
```

UPDATE: the question was altered to remove the reqirement for negative margin (which altered what was seen when at the top of the page). This simplifies things.

This snippet just draws the sloping part of the background first, up to 55% and then transparent, underneath the green and red are drawn horizontally.

```css
#vlikar {
  background: linear-gradient(110deg, #4587B3 10% 12%, #DCDCDC 12% 55%, transparent 55%), linear-gradient(green, red);
  height: 170px;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #696969;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 1349px;
}
```

```html
<section id="vlikar">
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all comments. I should be like this #vlikar3.

But I can't manage that after 55% last 2 colors should be ordinary horizontal linear-gradient(green, red).

Exceptionally horizontal (like in #vlikar2), not tilted.

-90px margin and other margins are not important here. The question is only how to combine, horizontal and tilted gradient.

```css
#vlikar3{
  background: linear-gradient(110deg, #4587B3 10% 12%, #DCDCDC 12% 55%, white 55%, green, red);
  height: 170px; 
  color: #696969;
  width: 1349px; 
}
```

```html
            
    <section id="vlikar3">
  </section>
```

```css
#vlikar2 {
  background: linear-gradient(green, red);
  height: 80px;
  width: 1429px;
}
```

```html
        
    <section id="vlikar2">
  </section>
```